# Some doubts related to first **raspi-config** execution?

Tags: raspbian, wireless, software-installation, update, raspi-config

I am very new in RaspBerry. I have installed RaspBian and connect my RaspBerry to my home router and I can connect to it using ssh.

Now I have to do the first configuration by the use of the **sudo raspi-config** command, I am following this tutorial: http://www.robertawood.com/blog/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-initial-setup-headless-no-monitor-or-keyboard-needed/raspberry-pi-initial-setup-part-9-raspi-config.html

As you can see in the previous link show a screenshot of what should I have to see launching the **raspi-config** application, this is the tutorial screenshot:

[image]

Ok, my doubt is that, executing **raspi-config** I see a different menu, this one:

[image]

As you can see the menu voices are pretty difference from the tutorial screenshot.

In particular, in the tutorial say that the first operation to do is **check that I have the latest version of raspi-config** using the **update** menu voices that I don't have in my menu.

Why my menus is pretty different from the tutorial one? Have I some problem with my RaspBian installation? How can I update my **raspi-config** if I have not this menu voice?

I have also another doubt: into the USB port of my RaspBerry I have put a wireless network adapter (a TP-LINK, model: TL-WN725N that should be compatible with RaspBerry). Have I to configure it into **raspi-config** applications or later in some other way?

Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that you should update raspi-config and the reboot.

Then you can configure the wifi through the terminal, or just boot into desktop

startx

and then use the GUI.

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-3-network-setup/setting-up-wifi-with-raspbian

Comment: actually, if anything, that is the up-to-date raspi-config view...